# Replacing ID representing field with actual values depicted by ID when styling with data defined properties or Labeling?

Tags: qgis

I am currently using data defined properties and labeling to present pipes based on diameter.
I now have a dictionary table that has id's for every combination of diameter and material and I'm using it with the value relation widget.

I must find a way to access the value represented by the key in the diameter || material field.

An ugly way that solves this would be to use:

```
CASE
   WHEN id_material_diam in (id1, id2) THEN result_formula_containing_diameter
   WHEN id_material_diam diameter in (id3...) THEN ...
END
```

Is there an elegant way that I can access the actual values for which the ID is the key?

I am using QGIS 2.2 Valmiera

Comment: Have you tried to create a new column out of the two using the field calculator?

Comment: Instead of diameter + material (e.g. 300 Stell) I have now an id. The value behind the id shows on account of the value relation widget. The question is how to have this in the expressions. I know how to create a new column and fill it with the actual values but that would be redundant and I want to avoid that. Thank you anyway

Comment: Have you tried to create a join to the other layer?

Comment: Although not what I expected, that's clearly a more elegant solution. I guess sometimes one must be told that 1 + 1 = 2
Thank you Matthias.

Comment: Unfortunately I encountered a bug: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9783 as I wanted to use the values in data defined properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthias Kuhn has an acceptable answer although it's in the comment. Joining the dictionary table by ID and maybe hide the unneeded columns is enough.